# How to use actionlistener and other stuff to get the value of two text fields when button is clicked

Tags: java, compiler-errors, awt, actionlistener

I am making a java program that will connect to MS access and add entries, and i need to record the values of two text boxes when a button is clicked

I've searched online for how to get responses, but i don't know how to do that with two text fields. I also dont know how to get action listener to make the answers received.

```
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                {

                };
```

I expect it to be able to receive the answers, which i will use later to add to MS Access, but thats not important. It says actionlistener cannot be resolved to a type, and button cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

At its *most basic*, the solution would be something like:

```
   JTextField fieldOne = new JTextField();
    JTextField fieldTwo = new JTextField();
    JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");

    button.addActionListener(ev -> {
        String valOne = fieldOne.getText();
        String valTwo = fieldTwo.getText();

    });
```

That is, you would create two text fields and simply access their value from within the `actionPerformed` method of an ActionListener. ActionListener is a functional interface; therefore, if you are using Java 8+, you can use a lambda expression as above.

If you are using Java 7 or earlier, you can use an anonymous class or create a new class that implements the interface. It seems pretty common (though whether a best practice is debatable) to create a class that both extends Frame or similar and implements ActionListener. With this approach one can simply create an "actionPerformed" method within this Frame implementation. The Java  tutorials exemplify this approach: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: im trying to system out print this, but it says it cant be resolved to a variable

Comment: i figured it out, the out print needs to be in the button place. Thanks though